# gnu parallel with ffmpeg does not process first file

Tags: shell-script, ffmpeg, gnu-parallel

I have some files

```
Joapira___BERLINA_DEL_HIERRO.mp4
Joapira___EL_BAILE_DEL_VIVO.mp4
Joapira___EL_CONDE_CABRA.mp4
Joapira___FLAIRE.mp4
Joapira___MAZULKA_DEL_HIERRO.mp4
Joapira___MEDA_A_MANOLITO_DIAZ_ARTESANO_TALLISTA.mp4
```

that I want to convert to some other formats with `ffmpeg` and GNU `parallel`. For example to convert them to flac I do

```
parallel --bar ffmpeg -i "{}" -map_metadata 0 "{/.}.flac" ::: *
```

or to convert them to mp3 I do

```
parallel --bar ffmpeg -i "{}" -vn -ar 44100 -ab 128k -map_metadata 0 "{/.}.mp3" ::: $@
```

but the process continues forever and the first file is always missing. Why?

### Info

I am on Fedora 22 using

*GNU parallel 20160222*

and

*ffmpeg version N-80953-gd4c8e93-static http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/*

### Update

Fascinating, I tried it with *ffmpeg version 2.6.8* (comes with Fedora) and it works!! And even with the most recent static build from git it does not. :-(

## Update 2

When I run `ps auxwww` and search for ffmpeg I see all the jobs with the state *Rl*, except for the command of the file that is missing, which has the state *T*.

GNU parallel has the state *S+*, but sometimes during the processing of the working files changes to *R+*.

The man page of `ps` says the following about the states:

```
D    uninterruptible sleep (usually IO)
R    running or runnable (on run queue)
S    interruptible sleep (waiting for an event to complete)
T    stopped by job control signal
t    stopped by debugger during the tracing
W    paging (not valid since the 2.6.xx kernel)
X    dead (should never be seen)
Z    defunct ("zombie") process, terminated but not reaped by its parent

<    high-priority (not nice to other users)
N    low-priority (nice to other users)
L    has pages locked into memory (for real-time and custom IO)
s    is a session leader
l    is multi-threaded (using CLONE_THREAD, like NPTL pthreads do)
+    is in the foreground process group
```

Maybe this helps to understand the problem.

Comment: Fascinating, I tried it with *ffmpeg version 2.6.8 Copyright* (comes with Fedora) and it works!! But even with the most recent static build from git it does not. :-(

Comment: Does parallel -u make a difference?

Comment: No, `-u` doesn’t make a difference. My temporary workaround is to use the ffmpeg version shipped with Fedora, which is ok for these audio codec conversions. But it would be nice to know what is going wrong and if it’s also the case within other distributions.

Comment: Since you have a release that is working and a git version that is broken, you should be able to identify the git revision in which it broke. `git bisect run` is brilliant for that. By identifying the problematic change it can probably be determined whether this is an `ffmpeg` issue or a GNU `parallel` issue.

Comment: I tested in a Mac OSX El Captain with parallel 20160922 and ffmpeg version 3.2, and I'm having this *exact* problem: *the process continues forever and the **first file** is always missing.*, when trying to convert a bunch of flac files to mp3.

Comment: @OleTange I did use the static build from git which is offered by johnvansickle.com. Maybe somebody else is able to do the `git clone` and then `git bisect run` and compile `ffmpeg` and run a job with `parallel` waiting for it to finish in a specified time, hundreds of times, until the release when the bug occurs for the first time, is found. Maybe I’ll do that. Someday. (I would really like to do it now, but I have a lot of work for the next two weeks.)

Comment: @erik A default value was changed in the newest release of GNU Parallel. Can you test whether that change made a difference?

Comment: Oh no!  I updated my system to Fedora 24. Now the built-in ffmpeg has the same problem and I have no idea for a workaround. Please help! *Name: parallel, Version: 20160222, Release: 1.fc24* and *Name: ffmpeg, Epoch: 1, Version: 3.2, Release: 2.fc24*. Seems to be the same versions like @SomebodystillusesyouMS-DOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is —as suggested by @OleTange in a comment— to update to a newer version of parallel, i.e. `GNU parallel 20161122`. EVerything works again.

And it is better to protect the commands from shell interaction with single quotes, i.e.:

```
parallel --bar 'ffmpeg -i {} -map_metadata 0 {/.}.flac' ::: *
```

and

```
parallel --bar 'ffmpeg -i {} -vn -ar 44100 -ab 128k -map_metadata 0 {/.}.mp3' ::: $@
```

Comment: The quoting is only needed if you use shell interacting chars (which you do not in your example). If your quoting becomes too complex, consider writing a function instead: https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#EXAMPLE:-Calling-Bash-functions